# GetMethod.getResponseBodyAsString() to xml object

Tags: javascript, xml

using Javascript HttpClient i am running a get method on WebService which works fine and then i store Response in a variable resp_va as shown below.

snip from code below.

```
var httpGetMethod = new GetMethod(url);
httpClient.executeMethod(httpGetMethod);

var statuscode = httpGetMethod.getStatusCode();
var resp_va = httpGetMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

although output is in XML Format but to me Looks like it is string and therefore i am unable to parse it. Question is how can i convert "resp_va" in XML object before parsing it further?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: it is JavaScript. i will edit the question.